# Real time access to attributes in ATG/Endeca integration

Tags: atg, endeca

We are working with ATG/Endeca integration 11.2. One of the client requirements is a near real time access to some of the attributes from the Product Catalog. However, this isn't possible since baseline has to be run before the Endeca index can be updated.

Is the only solution to query ATG directly using droplets for the attributes that are critical or is there any other way to accomplish this? We are pushing the product catalog to CAS using ProductCatalogSimpleIndexingAdmin(no Forge is being used).

Comment: You can do a `Partial Update` but it all depends on the volume of attributes you want to be able to update.

Comment: The data is in the database prior to an index. The recommended way to retrieve data from the database is through repository items. To obtain the product item is typically performed through a droplet. To answer your question, although not the only way, this is the recommended way.

Comment: Thank you Matt, this is the way we decided to go with.